# Twitter like App rejected

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, app-store

I have an App which is rejected which behaves as the Twitter App on the ground that:

> 10.4 Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-app widget experiences will be rejected

with as description:

> We found your app includes a dashboard view which presents multiple
>   windows at once, and is therefore not in compliance with the App Store
>   Review Guidelines.
>
> The iOS Human Interface Guidelines allow for multiple screens in an
>   app but access to these screens should always be sequential, never
>   simultaneous.
>
> Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information.
>
> It would be appropriate to modify your app by determining an alternate
>   way users can accomplish the same task in a single screen or a
>   sequence of screens.

The screenshot attached is seen below. Can anybody explain what exactly the reason is, looking at the Twitter App. Anybody with a similar experience and a possible solution apart from completely dashing the current interface and putting the ordinary split view controller in?

[image]

Comment: It's similar to the twitter app, but can you actually interact with multiple screens at once?

Comment: One can't tell why your app was actually rejected. It's Apple's own damn illogic decision.

Comment: I guess you could, like the Twitter App, you could select a different article in the tableview to be shown. (if you do so, the other views move automatically out of view)

Comment: You know you can ask THEM about it, rather than US?

Comment: How is this a programing question?

Comment: You can respond to Apple via the interface when logged into ITC - challenge it - I've been there before. If you're lucky and happen to live worlds apart from Cupertino then they'll schedule a call with a representative - which I found very useful recently. Good luck!

Comment: I'm curious why this was down-voted. I could guess, or read someone else's guess, but how is someone supposed to address the concerns of a down-voter if he won't put it in words with his own name? (The rules allow for the OP to correct the problem, but what's the problem?)

Comment: Take your question over to UI StackExchange. It should fit better their, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I applaud your implementation, it wont make Apple approve you any faster or even at all.

The reason they are rejecting, as they say, is because you can interact with all of those views at once. Standard navigation would push one view over the top of the last using the navigationController and sliding effect. Because Apple views this as a widget type effect where everything is all still running at the same time, you are getting the boot.

One suggestion might be to take a look at how Path and Facebook are implementing the navigation controllers with the slide out effect. You could probably implement something similar where you can just slide the old and the new views on screen. You still need to completely obscure the other views I think to pacify Apple for this rejection. Sorry their ruling wasn't more favorable. Good luck with your appeal and/or corrections.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.I wasn't sure exactly what the issue was, but now I know how they define widgets. I guess I can just go back to the normal view controller. Just tried to do something nice as it works very well regarding an user experience.

Answer (score 0):

They also say going to the press upon rejection doesn't help your appeal. Just FYI. I went through one appeals process and said "My app is just like X" and they said (literally), "Thanks for your feedback, unfortunately...."

I'd keep your appeals to yourself (not trying to be mean).

Last piece of advice is to make sure there are no detectable errors or incomplete parts of your app. The more polished it is going in the better.

Comment: Thank. Well, I was not going to appeal it, as I am sure their reasoning for rejecting will not change, and I think even quoting other Apps like the Twitter App makes no difference. I was trying to understand what exactly the issue is

Comment: Totally understand. Let me update my answer too.